# How do I create and use a polymorphic relationship?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I am new to Ruby and I read about a "polymorphic relationship".

What I read was over my head. Can you help me understand what a polymorphic relationship is in simple terms?

Comment: you can look at railsguide
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding on [the post](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/howtos/db-relationships/polymorphic) suggested by Jinesh, the overall concept can be explained by this:

A `belongs_to` association is given by a field in a table that points to a record in another table. For example, if you want to model a `Person` and their address, you have

```
class Person
  has_one :address
end

class Address
  belongs_to :person #Has a field person_id
end
```

But then, if you have another model `Company` that will use addresses as well, you would have to share the field `person_id`. So you make it an `addressable_id`, and both Person and Company are "addressable" objects to the Address model. So, when you specify

```
class Person
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable
end
```

you're telling Rails that whenever you search for a person's address, it will look on the `addresable_id` field on the Address table.

Comment: You should add a modified version of the `Address` class with `belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true`. Other than that, nice answer.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at this one? http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/howtos/db-relationships/polymorphic

It would be good if you could ask specific questions which you are finding hard to understand so that the community can address that.